# What happened to Konohamaru's parents?

Tags: naruto

It is known that [Konohamaru](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Konohamaru_Sarutobi) is the grandson of the Third Hokage. Asuma is shown to be one of the Third Hokage's sons, but he is clearly named as Konohamaru's uncle. Are Konohamaru's parents ever shown and is their lack of appearance ever explained?

Comment: This goes for a lot of characters. If they are not a great ninja or if they did not die in battle, there not really worth mentioning.

Comment: That's true, but they are the son/daughter of the Third Hokage. One would think that they would be important.

Comment: i know this is old but from everything i'm seen i've come to think that its not that they werent mentioned because they werent good ninjas or were dead more irrelevant i think they werent ninjas to keep it short...

Comment: to add i think taking it as them not being ninjas so not mentioned would fit into it well. thought the only conflict i have.. well. i'd say if asked but it'd take abit....

Comment: As this question doesn't have an accepted answer, it seems like there is more to say, so it's fine to add another answer. Can you expand this answer to explain why you think this? Can you give some evidence from the series that supports your argument?

Comment: I'd guess that they are dead too, as certain dead characters are overlooked for the majority of the manga (ie Naruto's mother despite the fact she was the previous jinchuuriki)

Answer (score 9):

In **Boruto Oneshot** it is revealed that Konohamaru's parents were elite jounins part of the Anbu.

It is not specified if they are still alive or not.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

They weren't mentioned.

My guess is that they were alive and well, but just weren't important enough to be mentioned. Much like how Jiraiya's parents weren't mentioned (though Jiraiya did make a remark about them being alive, while Orochimaru's weren't).

If they had been dead, we can assume it would have affected Konohamaru's personality in the same way it affected Naruto and Sasuke.

Answer (score 2):

Konohamaru's parents were never mentioned, neither in the anime, nor in the manga.
Maybe his parents died on a mission, or they were still alive and simply never mentioned.